# This message keeps appearing and I dont know what to do

Tags: python-3.x

I copied and pasted some code from how to automate the boring stuff and this message keeps coming. I have tried changing the amount of spaces or tabs and tried various things with sublime text. Please help.

## Generate 35 quiz files.

```
for quizNum in range(35):

    # Create the quiz and answer key files.
     quizFile = open('capitalsquiz%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')
     answerKeyFile = open('capitalsquiz_answers%s.txt' % (quizNum + 1), 'w')

    # Write out the header for the quiz.
quizFile.write('Name:\n\nDate:\n\nPeriod:\n\n')
    quizFile.write((' ' * 20) + 'State Capitals Quiz (Form %s)' % (quizNum + 1))
    quizFile.write('\n\n')


         # TODO: Shuffle the order of the states.
                states = list(capitals.keys())
             random.shuffle(states)



         # TODO: Loop through all 50 states, making a question for each.
             for questionNum in range(50):

                 # Get right and wrong answers.
         correctAnswer = capitals[states[questionNum]]
            wrongAnswers = list(capitals.values())
            del wrongAnswers[wrongAnswers.index(correctAnswer)]
            wrongAnswers = random.sample(wrongAnswers, 3)
            answerOptions = wrongAnswers + [correctAnswer]
         random.shuffle(answerOptions)
```

Comment: The example has indentation errors you'll need to fix. And you haven't mentioned what the problem is!

Comment: What is this *"message"*?

Comment: You've not explained a problem or asked a question. You mention *This message keeps appearing*, but you don't bother to tell us what the message is that is appearing, despite the fact it's **on the screen right in front of you**. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**, and yet you can't be bothered to actually provide us with the necessary details to use to help you? There is absolutely no excuse for failing to include the error message in your post - again, *it's on your screen right in front of you*.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend going through a basic tutorial in python. You will find it useful in the future.

Python adheres to what is called "offside rule". This means the different blocks of code are recognized by indentation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule

When you copy paste the code from the internet to your editor, the indentation might get distorted. You would want to recheck the source and have the code aligned exactly as it is in the source.

PS: Please try to post the error message along with the code.